# Docker image for Kubeflow with Conda and GPU support

Tags: docker, kubeflow

I have issues to run [this repo](https://github.com/FrozenBurning/SceneDreamer) and so I decided to make a custom Docker image and to deploy it to Kubeflow. The image needs to interface with a GPU and to have CUDA installed. Does anyone have suggestions on how to do it?

My idea is to clone the repo and then run a `.sh` script, listing the steps described [here](https://github.com/FrozenBurning/SceneDreamer#installation).

The script I wrote (below) gives the error

```
 > [ 6/10] RUN ./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /opt/conda:                               
#9 0.242 PREFIX=/opt/conda                                                                         
#9 0.467 Unpacking payload ...
#9 0.469 qemu-x86_64: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /opt/conda]: exit code: 255
```

Here is my script:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Install base utilities
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y build-essentials  && \
    apt-get install -y wget &&
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install miniconda
ENV CONDA_DIR /opt/conda
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
     /bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda

# Put conda in path so we can use conda activate
ENV PATH=$CONDA_DIR/bin:$PATH

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

COPY command.sh /app

RUN chmod +x /app/command.sh && \
    /bin/bash /app/command.sh
```